# How do I get the text between two span classes using webdriver

Tags: html, webdriver

I need to get the text value 'UNITED STATES STORE' which is between two span classes. Can anybody please help me getting this text?

UNITED STATES STORE

Comment: <div class="link">
<span class="globe_1"></span>
UNITED STATES STORE
<span class="close_arw"></span>
</div>

Comment: What is your current code in webdriver? What have you tried?

Comment: Tried to get the text 'United States Store' which is a dynamic text using the below jQuery script. But its getting me the entire HTML code like '<span class="globe_1"></span>UNITED STATES STORE <span class="close_arw"></span>' instead of only the text. 

 
String storeNameinPage= (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery('.link').html()");

Can you pls advice me further.

Thanks,
Deepa Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Try below Xpath:-

```
//div[contains(.,'UNITED STATES STORE ')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank You Mr.Shubham Jain!
Its not working for me and more over I cant use the xpath you have suggested as its a dynamic Text which keeps changing based on the markets

Comment: You can pass your text by using a string variable but as you said you do not want to use xpath then it's fine ..